# Performing Sumifs on a closed WorkBook

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a Function routine in WorkBook1 that performs the Sumifs calculation on a closed WorkBook2. Does anyone know of any simple code?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?  Seeing what code you have will help someone help you more effectively.

Answer (score 2):

`SUMIF` function will **not work with closed** workbooks.

A workaround is to use a worksheet with **direct references to each significant cell** in the closed workbooks and do your `SUMIF` on this worksheet.