# Sumifs Sumproduct applied to linked Excel sheets

Tags: excel, sumifs, sumproduct

I use sumifs/sumproduct frequently. However, one issue is that if I use these formulae for data in an external spreadsheet, I need to open that external file before I refresh. Otherwise, error will occur. Is there a way to get around this, please? That is, still doing sumifs but no need to open the external file. Thanks.

PS: The background to this question is as below. I need to refresh some non-sumifs formulae in a tab; but in this tab there are also sumifs applied to external data. In this case, I need to open the external file even if sumifs are not what I want to refresh. Hope this makes the question clear.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-correct-a-value-error-in-the-sumif-sumifs-function-e65ce689-978e-44b1-a649-160ed5f13b5a

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39874936/formulas-not-updating-if-the-other-work-book-is-closed/39903738#39903738 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388144/performing-sumifs-on-a-closed-workbook